# How to convert the date & time string into current timezone date in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, date

```
$dt = '2013-03-15 02:15:33';
$dateTimeZone = new DateTimeZone('Asia/Karachi');
$dateTime = new DateTime($dt, $dateTimeZone);
$year = $dateTime->format('Y');
$month = $dateTime->format('m');
$day = $dateTime->format('d');
$hours = $dateTime->format('H');
$minutes = $dateTime->format('i');
$seconds = $dateTime->format('s');
$message_time_ago = $year . '-' . $month . '-' . $day . ' ' . $hours . ':' . $minutes. ':' . $seconds;
```

But it returns same '2013-03-15 02:15:33', however it should be '2013-03-15 11:15:33'.
Can anyone help me about this problem?

Answer (score 1):

This is how you do it:

```
$date = new DateTime('2013-03-15 02:15:33');
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Asia/Karachi'));

echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // 2013-03-15 07:15:33
```

Comment: not sure why you are expecting `2013-03-15 11:15:33`... perhaps your source date/time is from a different timestamp?

Comment: Thanks "Latheesan Kanes". It is working now. But i didn't understand the difference. Can you describe it in some words?